# capture http calls and headers in python

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

We are testing videos in our website, and in order to play it should authenticate the user, get the authorization for the device he is playing and so on, check his entitlements etc.,
we have many varieties of network and video types to test. And I am in process of writing script which checks one of those calls are working fine for all type of videos.
Which is a POST call and need to build the param/data to post. Theres  no direct way of getting one of the param value and this is how we do currently. We go to browser and play the video. Open the dev tools like firebug and capture the param value from the request header of the same call and use it in my script for rest of other 100 different calls to verify programmatically.

Is there a way in python to do the steps which we are manually doing? like open a url and capture all the calls which happens at the background just like how firebug does?

I am trying firePython, firelogger, mechanize to see if they help . but I have invested so much time figuring out doing this, so thought its time to approach some expert advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked at the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, it's generally quite pleasant to work with and might make your life easier.